# showModalDialog deprecated Chrome37, other suggestions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, modal-dialog, showmodaldialog

Does anyone have any viable suggestions for the replacement of the showModalDialog() functionality in Chrome 37?  I understand that there is the path until May 2015, but that's not 'viable' in my opinion, and if I can avoid changing everything to window.open() functions that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have some of the code you are tying use?  I see you've tagged jQuery. So I will provide a jQuery answer.

You can use the following code to 'open' or 'show' a jquery Dialog

```
$(divSelector).dialog('open');

$(divSelector).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 200,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {'Ok': function(){
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }}
});
```

the .dialog('open') will trigger the dialog to open up.  I am not sure how difficult it would be to wrap your dialog div in the $(divSelector).dialog tags and include the jQuery UI css and javascript into your application.